# Elastic Kubernets metrics

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, cpu-usage, metricbeat

I'm trying to convert the Kubernetes CPU metrics to % in Elastic.

There are two fields in Elastic for CPU - kubernetes.node.cpu.usage.nanocores (Node CPU Core usage nanoseconds) and kubernetes.node.cpu.usage.core.ns (CPU used nanocores). Can someone please help to understand how to calculate the % using these available metrics?

Comment: Is there are a specific reason you'd like to use elastic metrics instead of cAdvisor metrics or something else native to kubernetes? You can probably find a lot more online examples that way, like this one - https://github.com/google/cadvisor/issues/2026#issuecomment-730298376